# How can I print the integer taken as input without spaces?

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to print out the number entered by the user as a whole and want to ignore the spaces.

Like this:

```
int aValue;
cin >> aValue;
```

Here, suppose the user enters `49 506`, I want to print it as `49506`.

Comment: Can you give an example please?  It is unclear to me what you want

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also tell us the input as well as expected and actual output of the code you show us.

Comment: Get user input as a string, remove all spaces and then use `std::stoi()`. Your question is unrelated to output.

Comment: Do you want to read `12 3 4       5` and get the number 12345?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get a string from a user with spaces, note you need to use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for that, as `operator>>` would not accept spaces:

```
std::string str;
std::getline( cin, str );
```

then you use [`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) together with [`std::isspace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) to remove spaces from your string:

```
auto it = std::remove_if( str.begin(), str.end(), []( unsigned char c ) { return std::isspace(c); } );
str.erase( it, str.end() );
```

and then you convert your string to an `int` using [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
auto aValue = std::stoi( str );
```

you should also add error checking to your code handling error conditions as described in documentation.